# Why is assigning rvalue to lvalue member reference allowed in c++?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

After learning some Rust and its lifetime specifiers, borrowing semantics, etc, I came across a Rust sample which doesn't allow something like that which is allowed in C++. Why?

```
struct S {
    std::string& str;
    S(std::string&& value) : str(value) {}
};
```

Comment: That's because C++ has its reputation to keep. Specifically, the reputation for giving everyone every opportunity to shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: In `str(value)`, the `str` member variable is an **lvalue**, and the `value` parameter is an **lvalue**.  The caller's argument was an **rvalue**.

Comment: @Eljay "*The caller's argument was an **rvalue***" - or possibly an **xvalue**, such as the return value of `std::move()`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure. but an xvalue is also an rvalue.

Answer (score 4):

It is not allowed and would cause an error if you actually did try that.

However, the name of a variable is *always* an lvalue, not a rvalue. What type the variable is doesn't matter at all. You need to call `std::move` on it to turn it into a rvalue. That's what `std::move` does.

When using a rvalue reference variable it behaves exactly like a lvalue reference variable. Both refer directly to the bound object as a lvalue. They only differ in how they can or cannot be initialized and how they affect overload resolution and template argument deduction.

The point is to make it explicit when you potentially move from an object. Even if `value` is a rvalue reference, you may still use it multiple times in the function. But, usually, when you move from the referenced object, you can't use it afterwards anymore or at least it will lose its state. Therefore it must be clear where a potential move can happen while still allowing non-move usage. So the rule makes sense to enforce you to write `std::move` explicitly everywhere where a move might happen.

If the goal is prevent a user from constructing `S` from a temporary, which is reasonable, then you should delete the constructor completely:

```
S(std::string&& value) = delete;
```

(There are technically some issues with this. A better, but complex approach is to follow what [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper/reference_wrapper) does.)

However, the user already has to think about lifetime of the argument they pass to `S`. So you only really catch a small subset of potential mistakes with this. There is no way to protect the user from not keeping the passed object alive long enough. If you need to ensure this through `S`, then `S` must take (shared) ownership of the object, e.g. by using `std::unique_ptr` or `std::shared_ptr` instead of a reference. There is no borrow checker in C++ like there is in Rust to verify that the borrowed/referenced object is kept alive long enough.

C++ lifetime and ownership management is mostly based on convention together with some utilities like the smart pointers. There is no intrinsic core language enforcement aside from automatic storage duration, although core language features like rvalue references are designed to support the conventions, e.g. as I described above.

Comment: Yes I agree about your explanation but problem is I can use wrongly. And it allows it and so on. I mean I wanted to see `hoop you can't do this - etc` but no. Just I'm ignored and shot myself.

Comment: @Grayowl You are not using it wrongly. The way you use it should almost always be fine, just not performant. The default behavior here is the safe one. See my edit.

Comment: @Grayowl Whether you bind to an lvalue reference member or a rvalue reference member also doesn't (really) matter either. So if at all the issue is not value category, but just that you try to store a reference at all.